# Set theory question involving probability.

Tags: probability

Prove or give a numerical counterexample to the following statement: If $E$ is independent of
$F$ and $E$ is independent of $G$, then $E$ is independent of $F \cup G$.

I have looked at the definition of independence but cannot find a way to tie the definition to the union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Pick $F$ and $G$ such that $F \cap G$ is not independent of $E$. Assume the statement true and try evaluating $P(E \cap (F \cup G))$ in two ways.

Comment: Is this a counterexample or proof by contradiction?

Comment: If you get the idea, you can formulate it as whichever you prefer - there's not that much difference.